# Curious natural patterns on the surface of basalt blocks that make up the sidewalk

Tags: rocks, fossils, igneous

During one of my walks through the city streets, I noticed that some basalt blocks that make up the sidewalk have in their surface some very curious natural patterns:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The photos above was taken at the [Porto Alegre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porto_Alegre) city, Brazil. (Coordinates: [30°01′59″S 51°13′48″W](https://www.google.com/maps/place/30%C2%B001'59.0"S+51%C2%B013'48.0"W))

What are these fractal-like patterns? How and when are they formed? Is it some kind of organic formation? Is it living being or some kind of fossil?

Comment: Is that sloped at angle? Is it a street curb/gutter? What is the dividing line that cuts through the pattern? How old is the stonework. Location, climate?

Comment: https://www.sandatlas.org/dendritic-growth-in-crystals/

Comment: Dendrites , gradual crystal growth as the molten rock freezes. very similar to  patterns in as cast metals.

Comment: This looks dendritic pyrolusite, manganese oxide.

Comment: see answer several manganese oxides form that dendritic structures, but no pyrolusite

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are most likely manganese dendrites. It is not a fossil, and not organic. These usually form in cracks in rocks, and most likely this slab was broken along an existing crack.

You can read more about it now: https://www.mindat.org/min-26645.html

One comment: this is not basalt. Basalt is black. Most likely some form of limestone.

Answer (score 1):

They are quite pretty, but they are not fossils. They remind me of the patterns that frost sometimes makes on window panes. A similar process is at work here, though with mineral bearing water infiltration rather than frost being the cause. The water infiltration deposits crystals in the rock.